# Converting Pytorch bfloat16 tensors to numpy throws TypeError

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, floating-point, tensor

When you try to convert a Torch bfloat16 tensor to a numpy array, it throws a `TypeError`:

```py
import torch

x = torch.Tensor([0]).to(torch.bfloat16)
x.numpy()  # TypeError: Got unsupported ScalarType BFloat16

import numpy as np
np.array(x)  # same error
```

Is there a work-around to make this conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `numpy` [does not support bfloat16](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/19808)**. One work-around is to upcast the tensor from half-precision to single-precision before making the conversion:

```py
x.float().numpy()
```

The Pytorch maintainers are [also considering](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/90574) adding a `force=True` option to the `Tensor.numpy` method to this automatically.

** although [that may change](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/19808#issuecomment-1477207638) thanks to [work](https://github.com/jax-ml/ml_dtypes) by @jakevdp